# Import Oracle dump tables to Oracle Database in docker

Tags: oracle, docker, ubuntu, oracle-sqldeveloper, dbvisualizer

OS is Ubuntu 20.04. I have a Oracle Database 19c which is in docker. In details, In **/opt**, I create **oracle** folder with subfolders and give them grant. You see them in following:

```
sudo chmod 777 /opt/oracle/admin/
sudo chown -R root /opt/oracle/admin/
sudo chmod 777 /opt/oracle/oradata/
sudo chown -R root /opt/oracle/oradata/
sudo chmod 777 /opt/oracle/scripts/startup/
sudo chown -R root /opt/oracle/scripts/startup/
sudo chmod 777 /opt/oracle/scripts/setup/
sudo chown -R root /opt/oracle/scripts/setup/
```

Then I run the Oracle Docker image with this command:

```
sudo docker run --name oracledb --shm-size=4g -p 1521:1521 -p 5500:5500 -e ORACLE_SID=testdb -e ORACLE_PDB=testpdb -e ORACLE_PWD=Oracle123 -v /opt/oracle/oradata:/opt/oracle/oradata -v /opt/oracle/admin:/opt/oracle/admin -v /opt/oracle/scripts/startup:/opt/oracle/scripts/startup -v /opt/oracle/scripts/setup:/opt/oracle/scripts/setup oracle:19.3.0
```

After running Oracle, I open **sqlnet.ora** in **/opt/oracle/oradata/dbconfig/TESTDB** of the host and change its content. After making change, it is like this:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES=(ALL)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (EZCONNECT, TNSNAMES, HOSTNAME)
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT=8
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=8
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=8
```

Other two file are like this:
**listener.ora**

```
 LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
   (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
   )
  )
```

**tnsnames.ora**

```
TESTDB=localhost:1521/TESTDB
TESTPDB=
  (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
   (CONNECT_DATA =
     (SERVER = DEDICATED)
     (SERVICE_NAME = TESTPDB)
   )
  )
```

DEDICATED_THROUGH_BROKER_LISTENER=ON
DIAG_ADR_ENABLED = off

It is run without problem. I install Bbvis and create a User, but I cannot import any ".dmp" table.
Even though I can create user in Dbvis, UI Oracle does not work. I cannot see any thing in **localhost:5500/em**. It is strange for me.
Also, I install Sql developer to import the tables, but I cannot connect to database at all. I receive this error:

*Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: Got minus one from a read call*

I try to use **impdp** in docker like this:

`docker exec -it id_container impdp user/password DUMPFILE=cst.dmp`

but I receive this error:

*ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist*

Moreover, when I run this command:

```
sudo docker exec -ti 6e277a00b558 sqlplus system/Pass@TESTPDB
```

It wants me to enter user-name and password. I enter "system" and its password. But it is not accepted and I receive this error:

```
ERROR:
 ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
 ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
 Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
 Additional information: 4376
 Additional information: -179270649
 Process ID: 0
 Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

I search a lot and test every way to import the dump files into Oracle Docker in Ubuntu. Even, I install **squirrelsql**, but It can import CSV files which I do not have.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: This error usually means that impdp tries to connect to a database that is not running. Often because the environment is not set correctly.

Comment: Dear @Suresh thank you for your feedback, would you please explain more? what is direcotory parameter?

Comment: Dear @D. Mika, if you mean setting ORACLE_HOME, I cannot set it, because it is already set in docker.

Comment: Check this [example](https://marceloochoa.blogspot.com/2017/06/using-datapump-on-oracledocker.html)

Comment: Dear @Suresh , I do your suggestion and receive error. So, I update my question. Would you please see it? Many thank.

Comment: Add environment variable `-e ORACLE_SID=CDBNAME`.and verify instance is up and running

Comment: Does container status shows up and healthy with the command `container ps a `

Comment: @Suresh, I use ** -e ORACLE_SID=TESTDB**. What do you mean about ```CDBNAME```?

Comment: @Suresh, yeah, I check container with **docker ps -a**, it is healthy.